# Не открывается конструктор android в Visual Studio

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Недавно обновил Visual Studio.
Создаю новый проект - Visual C# - android - blank app

У меня установлен Xamarin, соответственно появляется папка Resources->Layout->Main.axml

Дважды кликаю по Main.axml - не запускается конструктор, только открывается код, кликаю правок кнопкой - запустить в конструкторе - то же самое.

Comment: проблема решена самостоятельно, кажется нужно было обновить android sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема решена самостоятельно, кажется нужно было обновить android sdk